# Djago template card alignement [Django 2.2]

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I Need your help please.

My envirenement is:
python 3.6.6
django 2.2

I want to generate some code like this using django template.

```html
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    actu1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu3
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu4
  </div>
</div>
<!--insert inside a new div (with class card-deck) the 5th actu and next one-->
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    actu5
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu6
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu7
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu8
  </div>
</div>
<!--insert inside a new div (with class card-deck) the 9th actu and next one-->
```

what I manage to do with django templates is as follows:

```html
{% extends 'actu/base_actu.html'%} 
{% load static %} 
{%block actumain%}
<div class="card-deck">
    {%for actu in actu%}
    <div class="card">
        { {actu.content }}
    </div>
    {%endfor%}
</div>
 {%endblock%}
```

which just gives the code as follows:

```html
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    actu1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu3
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu4
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu5
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu7
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu8
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu9
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu10
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu11
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    actu...
  </div>
</div>
```

Please, could you give me your idea to be able to generate such a code.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You must close the curly braces at `{ {actu.content }}` so it shoud lbe `{{actu.content }}`

Comment: why don't you prepare data in view by breaking list into list of lists of 4 elements

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So you think add another variable inside the wiew and call it's in the template and use the same code but for different list?

Comment: And if list size increase how to manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `forloop.counter0` and the `divisibleby` tempate tag like this:

```
{% for actu in actu %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" and not forloop.first %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" %}
        <div class="card-deck">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="card">
        {{ actu.content }}
    </div>
    {% if forloop.last %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here we first check if the loop counter is divisible by 4 and not the first iteration  if yes we render the closing div tag.
Next we if the loop counter is divisible by 4 and if so we render the opening div tag.
After this we render the individual cards.
Next we check if this is the last iteration if so we render the closing div tag.

Comment: Thank you, great idea :) it's works. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for item in actu %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisableby:4 %}
    <div class="card-deck">
    {% endif %}
        <div class="card">
            {{ item.content }}
        </div>
        {% if forloop.counter0|divisableby:4 or forloop.last %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it and give you a feedback (y)