# How can I use range in a for loop and use the range object as an index in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, loops, django-templates

I am trying to loop through a list of items to display in a Django template. I have read up on how you can create a range object in a few different ways to pass into the context. What I haven't been able to find, is how you can use the range object as an index, especially as a way to access items that are beyond the current index, i.e `print(myList[i+2])`. Is there a way to do this? Let's say I am passing a list in like so: `return render(request, 'index.html', {'lst': lst, 'range': range(0, len(lst), 3)})`

What I want:

```
{% for i in range %}
    {{lst.i.color}}
    {{lst.i+1.price}}
```

In my reading, I've seen how you can create a range object and use it like `{{lst.i.color}}`, but are you able to also do something like `{{lst.i+1.color}}`? If so, an example would be great. I know that `lst.i+1.color` does not work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You probably should not shadow `range` like that. Use another name

Comment: It is not clear what you expect `lst.i+1.price` to do, Django or not

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll switch that up.

Comment: DeepSpace, I want it to display the value of the object `lst[i+1].price`, but obviously that isn't how to do it.

Comment: Then did you try to do `{{lst[i+1].price}}` ? just keep in mind it will cause an index error on the last iteration

Comment: @DeepSpace that does not work in Django Template Language. You might be thinking about jinja here.

Comment: @J.B. Why do you want to display the next price for the current colour anyway?

Comment: Abdul, it's just an example. I am using Bootstrap grid system to display images that I have in a list. I want the images to display 3 in a row. When i use `{% for item in myList %}` and then do the Bootstrap grid code, it displays the same item 3 times in a row. I want the first item in the list, then the next, and then the next. Then, new row, next item, etc.

Comment: @J.B. check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65796788/14991864) on this other question. Although not very beautiful I do something like what you want.

Comment: @J.B. Although I would suggest doing something like `my_iter = iter(lst)` and then passing `{'three_zip': zip(my_iter, my_iter, my_iter)}`. All of the logic done in the view itself. Now in the template: `{% for val1, val2, val3 in three_zip %}`

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat, your last answer worked perfectly. Today I learned something new. Thanks so much. If you turn that comment into an answer I will accept it. I appreciate it.